# Stretch button full screen flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm writing an app in flutter where there is only one button, I want to stretch this button for full screen width and height, how best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutBuilder` widget could come in handy for this. It provides the `BoxConstrains` of the parent widget, which includes the width and height. In your case, the parent widget would probably be the `Scaffold` which is covering the whole screen.

You then can use the `BoxContrains` provided to you to return the accordantly sized button from the build function, which then gets displayed. You can set the size of the button either with the `SizedBox` widget or directly in its style.

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder( 
  builder: (context, constrains) => TextButton(
      child: const Text('Your button'),
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          fixedSize: Size(
              constrains.maxHeight, 
              constrains.maxHeight
          ), 
              maximumSize: Size.infinite
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
      ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1.0, // width w.r.t to parent
            heightFactor: 1.0, // height w.r.t to parent

            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("+"),
            ),
          )
```

OR

```
Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

OR

```
Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

OR

```
Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("+"),
          ),
        )
```

**FullCode**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Mainwidget()));
}

    class Mainwidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const Mainwidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MainwidgetState createState() => _MainwidgetState();
    }
    
    class _MainwidgetState extends State<Mainwidget> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: FractionallySizedBox(
                widthFactor: 1.0, // width w.r.t to parent
                heightFactor: 1.0, // height w.r.t to parent
    
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("+"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```